# Add row values as new columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like follows:

```
A     B     C
a1    b1    c1
a1    b2    c2
a2    b1    c3
a2    b2    c4
```

I want to convert it to something like:

```
A     B1        
a1    c1        
a2    c3
```

or

```
A     B1   B2     
a1    c1   c2     
a2    c3   c4
```

The values in B which are repeated are column names whose values are in C column. I want to add all or some of them as the columns of the dataframe

In fact the dataset is created by flattening a tree, there are more columns each of which is an internal node. the first column is root, C are leaves

These are some tries by me:

```
desired_cols = ["b1","b2"] # desired cols 
df = main_df[main_df['B'] == "b1"]
for c in desired_cols:
    new_col = main_df[main_df['B'] == c]['C']
    df[c] = new_col
```

However, it doesn't work and new columns are not aligned vertically. It adds `nan` in new columns.

Comment: Could you explain the logic you're trying to achieve here... it's probably me but I'm not seeing what the pattern is

Comment: @JonClements the values in B which are repeated are column names whose values are in C column. I want them to be columns of dataframe.

Comment: Okay... and the desired output is definitely 4 rows and not 2? ('cos if two are fine - that's just a pivot...)

Comment: @JonClements Twos are fine!

Comment: @JonClements In fact the dataset is from flattening a tree, there are more columns each of which is an internal node. the first column is root, C are leaves

Comment: Then Paul's answer is what I would have gone for...

Comment: @JonClements, I tried `df = df.pivot('qid', columns='field')` but it throws ` ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape `

Comment: @JonClements Please provide a general answer, it was just an example... How can I specify all other columns except for B and C as pivot columns if that is what you mean.

Comment: @JonClements now I tried `df = df.pivot(df.columns - ["B","C"], columns='B')`, I recieve `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (2,) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`df.pivot('A', columns='B')`

You will get only two rows, but your four rows are 2 rows duplicated anyhow.

```
    A   C
B       b1  b2
0   a1  c1  c2
1   a2  c3  c4
```

##### Update

If you want to dynamically select your pivot index, you can select all columns present in your df, except 'B' and 'C' as such:

`df2 = df.pivot(index=list(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['B', 'C'])]), columns='B')`

##### Update 2

If you want to only create specific columns from values in B, slice the dataframe first:

`df2 = df[df.B.isin(desired_cols)].pivot('A', columns='B').reset_index()`

Where `desired_cols = ['b1']` or `desired_cols = ['b1', 'b2']`

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Please provide a general answer, it was just an example... How can I specify all other columns except for B and C as pivot columns if that is what you mean.

Comment: now I tried `df = df.pivot(df.columns - ["B","C"], columns='B')`, I recieve `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (2,) `

Comment: `df.columns - ['B','C']` is not a valid way to subtract 'B' and 'C' from `df.columns`

Comment: Thank you very much, the first update works, however for the second what should I use for "A"? should it be like update 1 by excluding columns B and C?

Comment: Try out both, and use what suits your case best. Since you gave a generalised example, I can't quite grasp what other possibilities there might be.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, yeah for "A" I used the excluding code in update 1.

Comment: You may consider voting the question, based on the new updates